# @ManyToOne conflicts with JpaRepository

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

@ManyToOne or @OneToOne will replace the joined column with an entity, but how would I do when I want to use JpaRepository to query by that joined column? There's seems a conflict.

```
@Entity
public class Type {
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    private Type type;
}

public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
    List<Item> findByTypeId(Long typeId);
}
```

It throws error "property typeId not found", which makes sense because it's surely not in the class "item", instead an entity "type". But how could I query Item by type_id in this situation? And if I declare property typeId, it will throw error duplicated mapping for column "type_id".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it with `_` like

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
    List<Item> findByType_Id(Long typeId);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can specify the property name, not just use the default patten?

Comment: What do you meant by default pattern. You can specify any property of a subclass after _

Comment: I mean, what if I don't want to do it with "_" and specify my own name because it gonna cause other ones confusing what this property from. Something like @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", propertyName="typeId"), so I can name the method findByTypeId().

Comment: What you need to observe here is you are not writing the query. Spring data is creating query for you based on your method name. So you need to specify method names in a way spring data wants you to specify. If you want to define your own Method Names, you can do it but you need to specify the Query associated with that using `@Query(....)`